# Finding the average number/grade using data from 4 different arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I am working with 4 arrays, each array contains students last names and their test grades for 4 different tests. What I am trying to do is find the average For each student, calculate and display their average grade. How would I find Smiths average grade from all 4 arrays? I am very new to PHP so any directions would be useful. Thank you!

PHP:

```
$testOne = array (
        'Smith'=> 98,
        'Johnson' => 67,
   );

 $testTwo = array (
        'Smith'=> 100,
        'Johnson' => 85,
   );

 $testThree = array (
            'Smith'=> 78,
            'Johnson' => 92,
    );

   $testFour = array (
            'Smith'=> 91,
            'Johnson' => 88,
    );
```

I found one way to get the average but can anyone tell me if there is a more efficient way? I created separate arrays for each student and then divided by the count.

```
 $smith = array(98,100,91,75);
   $johnson = array(67,88,85,81)

   echo('Smiths average test score is ' . array_sum($smith) / 4);
```

Comment: Thank you Leo, so just create another array with each student as their own array? Or do you mean put all students and all test scores into one array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$TestResult = [
   'Smith' => ['98', '100', '78', '91'],
   'Johnson' => ['67', '85', '92', '88']
];

$Total = array_sum($TestResult['Smith']); // We are getting the array sum.
$Average = $Total/count($TestResult['Smith']); // the average is being calculated.

echo $Average;
```

https://3v4l.org/U3gCA

You can do this way.

**Reference :**

- [manual count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)
- [source count](https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src@master/ext/standard/array.c#776)
- [manual array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- [source array_sum - source](https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src@master/ext/standard/array.c#5877)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose students have given four tests(as you said above) namely `$testOne`, `$testTwo` and `$testThree` and `$testFour`, then create an array like this,

```
$array = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four');
```

Declare a variable to capture total score,

```
$totalScore = 0;
```

Declare a student's name whose average score you want to calculate,

```
$candidate = 'Smith';
```

Use a `foreach` loop sum the *candidate's* total score of all subjects,

```
foreach($array as $a){
    $totalScore += ${'test'.$a}[$candidate];
}
```

Finally, calculate that candidate's average score like this,

```
$averageScore = $totalScore / count($array);
```

Here's the complete code:

```
$array = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four');
$totalScore = 0;
$candidate = 'Smith';
foreach($array as $a){
    $totalScore += ${'test'.$a}[$candidate];
}
$averageScore = $totalScore / count($array);

echo $averageScore;
```

---

Reference links:

- [**`foreach` loop**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [**Assignment operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)
- [**Variable variables**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
- [**String operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: One last question Rajdeep, I see where I declare which person I want to calculate the score for by declaring $candidate, would this same method be the most effective way if lets say there were 15 students in the class and I needed to find the average for all of them?

Comment: @WCA You mean average of all students or average of each student?

Comment: @Rajdeep, I apologize, I was not clear, yes the average for EACH student, so smiths average, johnsons average, Fields average etc.

Comment: @WCA In that case, declare `$candidate` as an array and use nested `foreach` loops to find each student's average, like this: [https://pastebin.com/pye83QAc](https://pastebin.com/pye83QAc). Edit: Here's the live example: https://eval.in/1042497

Answer (score 0):

if php 7+

```
$test[]['Smith'] = 98;
$test[]['Johnson'] = 67;

$test[]['Smith'] = 100;
$test[]['Johnson'] = 85;

$test[]['Smith'] = 78;
$test[]['Johnson'] = 92;

$test[]['Smith'] = 91;
$test[]['Johnson'] = 88;
```

then you can do the math

```
$avarage['Smith'] = array_sum(array_column($test, 'Smith'))/count($test);
$avarage['Johnson'] = array_sum(array_column($test, 'Johnson'))/count($test);
```

or even make a function

```
function avarage($name, $test)
{
   return array_sum(array_column($test, $name))/count($test);
}
```

calling function:

```
$avarage['Smith'] = avarage('Smith', $test);
$avarage['Johnson'] = avarage('Johnson', $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a total array of all the arrays and loop one of them to get the student names.
Use the name in array_column to get the values from all the students scores and calculate the average.
Add the values to an associative array for convince.

```
$total = [$testOne, $testTwo, $testThree, $testFour];

foreach($total[0] as $name => $val){
    $averages[$name] = array_sum(array_column($total, $name))/count($total);
}
var_dump($averages);
```

Returns:

```
array(2) {
  ["Smith"]=>
  float(91.75)
  ["Johnson"]=>
  int(83)
}
```

If there had been more students this method would catch them all and just append the array.

https://3v4l.org/Lk1aL